# Dumping h264 stream into a mp4 container

Tags: ffmpeg, h.264, mp4

I would like to know how can I dump the h264 raw stream from a network camera into a mp4 container file. I need to do it with C++, any library? can I do it by myself?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Depends on how the stream is formatted. `mp4box -add input.264 -new output.mp4` could work for example.

Comment: Please, if you read my question you will show I need to do this programatically.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 7 and later has API that can write video containers.  Search MSDN for Sink Writer and Microsoft Media Foundation.  It is the successor to DirectShow.  There is specific mention for support of MP4 file sink and H.264 video encoding/decoding.  This is one option.

Comment: Thanks Jaden. I would love to do it in a platform-indepentent manner.

Answer (score 0):

Check out libmp4v2 @ https://code.google.com/p/mp4v2/

It is pretty straight forward to use.

HandBrake uses it. You can download source from @ https://handbrake.fr/downloads.php for reference